# Как верно сформировать запрос к Яндекс Картам? для подключения к C#

Tags: c#, яндекс-карты, gmap.net

Имеется код C# для геомаршрутизации, где хочется синхронизировать Яндекс.Карты.
Как верно сформировать запрос к Яндекс Картам?
Вот такой код:
//Формируем запрос к АР маршрутов Google. string url = string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin={0},&destination={1]&sensor=false&language=ru&mode={2}", Uri. EscapeDataString(textBox1.Text), Uri. EscapeDataString (textBox2. Text), Uri. EscapeDataString(mode [comboBox1 . SelectedIndex1));